# Updating and persisting spring cloud config sever properties at runtime

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I do not have any persistence layer in my application but I want to add some application properties values which should be editable at runtime and the edited properties should be persisted. So that next time when the app redeploys or restarts the previously edited properties apply. Please note that there is no way to store the properties in any database.its a light stateless application without any database. But needs configurations to be changed and persisted at runtime

Trying to see if I can use spring cloud config server for the above use case. But as there is no application database wanted to understand where does spring cloud config server store it's configurations by default. And can the edited properties be stored in the default persistence of spring cloud config server